# Как написать условие в макросе?

Tags: c++

Есть у меня вот такой рабочий файл

```
#ifndef ANDROID_LOGGING_H
#define ANDROID_LOGGING_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <vector>

#define APP_NAME "MyApp"
#define IS_DEBUGG true

#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGE(...) ((void) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))

#define CHECK(condition)                                                   \
  if (!(condition)) {                                                      \
    LOGE("*** CHECK FAILED at %s:%d: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, #condition); \
    abort();                                                               \
  }

#endif //ANDROID_LOGGING_H
```

Я вижу, что в макросе `CHECK` используется условие

```
#define CHECK(condition)                                                   \
  if (!(condition)) {                                                      \
    LOGE("*** CHECK FAILED at %s:%d: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, #condition); \
    abort();                                                               \
  }
```

Значит использовать условия в макросах можно, от сюда я придумал дописать условие в лог

Вот так

```
#define LOGE(...) ((void) if(IS_DEBUGG) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Но теперь везде где я использую `LOGE("error");` мне подсвечивает и говорит, что не хватает какого то знака `syntax error  (, ), ;`

Как написать условие в макросе?

**EDIT**

```
#define IS_DEBUGG true

#if(IS_DEBUGG)
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGW(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGE(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#endif
```

Comment: во первых вы зачем-то приводите `if` к `void` - это невозможно. Во-вторых, добавте `;` в конце

Comment: Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к "условию в макросе", а вызвана каким-то странным `(void)` перед `if`. Что там делает этот `(void)` и зачем вы его туда вписали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это условие не в макросе, а вставляется в код. Условные директивы для препроцессора пишутся так:

```
#if(IS_DEBUGG)
#define LOGE(...) ((void) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
#else
#define LOGE(...)
#endif
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос имплементацию. Если я правильно понимаю, то без `else` при условии что `IS_DEBUG false` я не могу использовать условные дерективы? Я получаю ошибку `error after macro substitution` как будто он не видит ничего что не входит в условие

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko eckb `IS_DEBUG` false, то содержимое блока `if` игнорируется, это же текстовый препроцессор

Answer (score 2):

В макросах почти нет никаких "можно" или "нельзя". Макросы - это текстовые подстановки. Писать в них можно почти что угодно. Фактически "использоваться", правда, это все будет не в макросе, а в месте его подстановки.

Вы все сделали почти правильно, кроме какого-то странного `(void)`, который вы впихнули в ваш макрос ни к селу, ни к городу. Неудивительно, что в месте подстановки такого макроса возникает ошибка из-за этого `(void)`. Правильно

```
#define LOGE(...)\
  if (IS_DEBUGG)\
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Можно добавить `(void)` непосредственно перед вызовом функции, как это сделано в остальных вызовах, если этого `(void)` требует принятые у вас правила написания кода

```
#define LOGE(...)\
  if (IS_DEBUGG)\
    ((void) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Однако такой вариант макроса страдает от одной неприятной проблемы, которая присуща и приведенному вами макросу `CHECK` тоже. Если кто-то когда-напишет вполне естественно выглядящий код вида

```
if (условие1)
  CHECK(условие2);
else
  что-то;
```

то такой код приведет к ошибке "оторванного" `else`.

А если кто-то использует

```
if (условие)
  LOGE(параметры);
else
  что-то;
```

то такой код будет проинтерпретирован компилятором как

```
if (условие)
  if (IS_DEBUGG) 
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, параметры);
  else
    что-то;
```

То есть `else` будет неожиданно отнесен совсем не к тому `if`, к которому собирался отнести его автор кода.

По этим причинам при написании подобных макросов следует придерживаться определенных правил. Как минимум, в `if` верхнего уровня старайтесь всегда указывать обе ветки `if` и ваш код писать именно в ветке `else`

```
#define CHECK(condition)                                                   \
  if (condition); else {                                                   \
    LOGE("*** CHECK FAILED at %s:%d: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, #condition); \
    abort();                                                               \
  }                                                                        

#define LOGE(...)                                                          \
  if (!IS_DEBUGG); else                                                    \
    ((void) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Но лучше такие составные макросы всегда заключать в операторные скобки `do ... while (0)`

```
#define CHECK(condition)                                                     \
  do                                                                         \
    if (!(condition)) {                                                      \
      LOGE("*** CHECK FAILED at %s:%d: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, #condition); \
      abort();                                                               \
    }                                                                        \
  while (0)

#define LOGE(...)                                                            \
  do                                                                         \
    if (IS_DEBUGG)                                                           \
      (void) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, APP_NAME, __VA_ARGS__);  \
  while (0)
```

В вашем случае, когда условие является константой препроцессора (`IS_DEBUGG`) лучше, наверное, применить принципиально иной подход из ответа @VTT. Однако это ни в коем случае не обязательно. Ваш оригинальный подход вполне жизнеспособен и обладает своим набором преимуществ.